In the Non-Abelian Higgs Mechanism, what is the definition of the resulting massive vector fields?
In the Abelian case of the Higgs mechanism, say $U(1)$, the way the Goldstone bosons that arise due to SSB are "eaten" by the gauge vectors is usually explained by going to the unitary gauge. This way, the new gauge bosons are defined as:
$A_{\mu}^{'}=A_{\mu}+\frac{1}{gv}\partial_\mu \chi$
Where $\chi$ is the Goldstone being eaten. With this definition we can see that the Goldstone is actually the longitudinal mode of the massive gauge field, which now propagates 3 d.o.f. Furthermore, the resulting Lagrangian doesn't contain any terms that explicitly involve the Goldstone bosons by themselves.
Now, my issue comes in the Non-Abelian case. One can straightforwardly mimic the procedure up to the transformation into the unitary gauge (Most resources I've found go straight into the unitary gauge and just assume that the massive gauge bosons have "eaten" the Goldstones, i.e. they don't explicitly perform the transformation, see https://arxiv.org/abs/2409.09211 or https://www2.physik.uni-muenchen.de/lehre/vorlesungen/sose_22/Introduction-to-Physics-of-Neutrinos/Materials/SMcourse.pdf).
However, now that we are in a non-Abelian case, the transformation isn't as before. We have, for a given transformation $U(x)$ which takes $\phi$ (The field that has acquired a VEV) to the unitary gauge, the following transformations for the gauge fields,
Infinitesimally:
$A_{\mu}^{a'}=A_{\mu}^{a}+\frac{1}{g}\partial_\mu \chi^{a} +f^{abc}A_{\mu}^{b}\chi^{c}$
or,
Finite:
$A_{\mu}^{a'}=U(x)A_{\mu} U^{-1}(x) -\frac{i}{g}\big(\partial_{\mu}U(x)\big)U^{-1}(x)$
Focusing on the infinitesimal form, we see that the resulting gauge field isn't a massive vector field carrying 3 d.o.f. Rather, the first 2 terms can be thought of as representing a massive vector field, but the third term actually represents non-zero coupling terms between massless gauge fields ($A_{\mu}^{a}$) and Goldstone fields.
Thus, if the unitary gauge is one in which all explicit terms involving the Goldstone bosons disappear, then it means we have to define our new massive gauge fields as $A_{\mu}^{a'}=A_{\mu}^{a}+\frac{1}{g}\partial_\mu \chi^{a} +f^{abc}A_{\mu}^{b}\chi^{c}$, which I can't make sense of as a massive vector field that carries 3 d.o.f. (i.e. it carries more than 3 d.o.f)
Otherwise, if we define our massive gauge fields as the first two terms in $A_{\mu}^{a'}=A_{\mu}^{a}+\frac{1}{g}\partial_\mu \chi^{a} +f^{abc}A_{\mu}^{b}\chi^{c}$, then we are left with explicit terms containing the massless gauge fields and the Goldstones, in which case it doesn't agree with the definition of the Unitary gauge.
Thus, I am rather lost on how to tackle/interpret this. I understand that the Goldstones are actually eaten by the gauge fields, however, I would like to see explicitly how they are being eaten for the case of a non-Abelian Higgs mechanism.

You may be deeply misunderstanding the symbols and what they mean. In the finite-gauge-transformed case, $A_\mu^{a~ '}$ represent massive gauge fields, manifestly in the lagrangian, which contains neither would-be-goldstons $\chi^a$ nor  $A_\mu^a$s anymore: Try the pure SU(2) case, without hypercharge, and convince yourself the finite gauge transformation actually works. Look at all terms.

@CosmasZachos I don't understand, how can $A_{\mu}^{a '}$ not depend/contain on $A_{\mu}^{a}$? As I understand it any gauge transformation results in a new gauge field $A_{\mu}^{a '}$ however, these new fields are always related to the previos fields $A_{\mu}^{a}$ precisely by a gauge transformations. So I don't understand why you can say that $A_{\mu}^{a '}$ doesn't contain/is related to $A_{\mu}^{a}$ or the Goldstones, which in this case are simply the parameters of the gauge transformation.

@CosmasZachos What I am asking is: I know that if we work directly in the unitary gauge, the gauge bosons are massive and we don't have any mixing terms between Goldstone and gauge fields. However, I would expect that if I start in a different gauge and then transform into the unitary gauge I would be able to observe the same Lagrangian, but in the process I would have to define my new gauge fields and thus "see" how they relate to the "original" massless fields and would-be goldstones

You are misreading my statement: it is the Lagrangian which fails to contain the old variables. You have made a change of variables and gotten a lagrangian containing a new gauge field and a mass term for it, and no goldstons. Not decoupled goldstons, the goldstons have disappeared.

@CosmasZachos That is precisely what I am trying to observe but I am making a mistake somewhere I can't pinpoint. I know that when I move into the unitary gauge, all the terms involving the goldstones should disappear and I should be left with only the new gauge fields and the higgs. However, when I perform the transformation (using either the infinitesimal or finite form) I get some terms (coming from the non-Abelian nature) that if I include them in the definition of the new gauge fields, I can't make sense of the fields. If I leave them out, they would seem to contradict the unitary gauge.

You may be deeply misunderstanding the symbols and what they mean. In the finite-gauge-transformed case,
$A_\mu^{a~'}$ represent massive gauge fields, manifestly in the lagrangian, which (Lagrangian) contains neither would-be-goldstons $^a$, nor $A_\mu^{a}$s anymore.
Focus on the essence of the Higgs mechanism, not the peripheral irrelevancies.
For simplicity, consider the SM, take a vanishing Weinberg angle, so ignore the weak hypercharge U(1) and its gauge field. You are completely SSBreaking an SU(2).  Ignore the fermion sector.
Indulging cavalier normalizations, ignore the gauge-kinetic, Yang-Mills, term, which is unaffected by a gauge transformation $U=e^{-i\vec \chi\cdot\vec\tau/v}$ to primed variables, and focus on just the Higgs term in the Kibble polar parameterization, with $\langle \vec\chi\rangle =0$ and $\langle h\rangle=0$,
$$
\phi= \frac{h+ v}{\sqrt{2}}e^{i\vec \chi\cdot\vec\tau/v}\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \leadsto $$
$$ 
D_\mu \phi = (\partial_\mu -ig \vec A_\mu\cdot \tau /2)\left ( \frac{h+ v}{\sqrt{2}} U^\dagger \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\right ) \leadsto \\
(D_\mu\phi)^\dagger D^\mu\phi   +\lambda (\phi^\dagger \phi -v^2/2)^2\\ = 
 \frac{g^2(v+h)^2}{8}\vec A_\mu'\cdot \vec A^{\mu ~'} +{\lambda\over 4} ((h+v)^2-v^2)^2+ \tfrac{1}{2}\partial_\mu h \partial^\mu h ~ ,
$$
up to factors and normalizations. There is a mass for the three new primed gauge fields, a mass for h, and  h interaction terms.
So all unprimed gauge fields have disappeared in this nonlinear variable transformation, and so have the three goldstons $\vec \chi$.   So all old variables, representing 3 d.o.f. in all,  have disappeared. Who "eats" whom is a popular metaphor.

Thanks! I understand. What I can't reconcile is the fact that if $A_{\mu}^{'}$ carry 3 d.o.f since they are massive vector fields, how is this shown in the gauge transformation?. That is, when you go to the unitary gauge, you have a transformation for $A_{\mu}^{a'}$, which involves $A_{\mu}^{a}$ (which carries 2 d.o.f), $\chi^{a}$ (1 d.o.f) and in the non-abelian case $f^{abc}A^{b}\chi^{c}$ (One can check that it is also true in the finite case). The addition of this last term would seem to imply that $A_{\mu}^{'}$ carries more than 3 d.o.f. and that is what I am trying to understand.

It is a nonlinear transformation: is this what is bothering you? As a rule, you identify and survey d.o.f. from the lagrangian that describes them and the superfluous symmetries. It is a bit of a delicate art, but if you have an answer that cannot be interpreted differently... why would you shadow-box with ghosts? Actually, you will, when you learn about the equivalence theorem in scattering....

Well, yes. I thought maybe even in the non-abelian case there would be a nice way to show that the $A_{\mu}^{'}$ carried only 3 d.o.f. and that they were: 2 from the massless $A_{\mu}$ and 1 from the eaten Goldstone. Because if there isn't a way then how can I be sure that the Goldstones are actually being "eaten" by $A_{\mu}^{'}$. This is all rather a sanity check. I could work from the unitary gauge and assume $A_{\mu}^{'}$ are massive and carry 3 d.o.f. but I wanted to see if there is an explicit way to check this in the non-Abelian case.

No, I think I found a way to make sense of it in a different approach. In going to the Unitary Gauge, instead of thinking of a gauge transformation, if I regard the definitions as gauge choices instead, then I don't have any issues with the non-Abelian theories and all is well. Thanks!

This is the starting point, of course. In the unitary gauge. the d.o.f. are self-evident, and there are no phantasies of "eating". In practice, the unitary gauge is to demonstrate this, and little else! If the answer helped, you could accept or upvote.
